# How Do I get 'font-weight: lighter' to work in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

There doesn't appear to be any difference between 'font-weight: normal' and 'font-weight: bold' in Google Chrome (and probably Safari). Has anyone found a way to invoke the 'font-weight: thinner' in Chrome the way that Firefox does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31833) in Chrome fixed in latest development builds:

There is a [temporary workaround](http://doctype.com/font-showing-bold-only-chromesafari) you can also try:

> To enable the `font-weight` property on a `@font-face` font which doesn't have a bold font defined, you need to explicitly define **`font-weight:normal;`** and **`font-style:normal;`** in the `@font-face` definition. Example:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GriffosFont Regular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('fonts/GriffosFont.eot');
    src: local('GriffosFont Regular'), local('GriffosFont'), url('fonts/GriffosFont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/GriffosFont.\
ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/GriffosFont.svg#GriffosFont') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to add this to your CSS:

```
* {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
```

Answer (score -2):

`font-weight: lighter;` was not working for me so I used `font-weight: normal;` instead, which worked for my purpose. not sure what's going on with chrome right now...

Comment: Note that `font-weight: lighter` makes the font «one step» lighter, so an element that inherits bold would then be rendered with normal font-weight instead. If you have a specific font-weight in mind, it is better to specify it directly. `font-weight: 200` will yield a light font.

Comment: I agree. For what it is worth, at the time of this post, `font-weight: lighter;` was not working in chrome. I could dig through my commits to find the exact version of chrome that had the bug and I'm sure it has been fixed by now (five years later).