# Segoe UI Light Font Not displaying properly in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I am using Segoe UI Light font in my website.

the css used is as follows.

```
.divMainHeader
{
font-family:Segoe UI;
font-size:28pt;
font-weight:lighter; 
width:100%
}
```

But Google Chrome is not rendering this font properly. I am getting a bold font of Segoe UI Light in Chrome.

The Image.
[image: The Screen Shots joined of different browsers.]

The versions of browsers i'm using.

> **Internet Explorer : 9**
>
> **Mozilla Firefox : 21**
>
> **Google Chrome : 27**

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705791/how-do-i-get-font-weight-lighter-to-work-in-google-chrome

Comment: @ralph that didn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

Its difficult to get this working in Firefox. Font weight 300 doesnt work few time in all versions. The below code worked for me and compatible with all browsers.

```
 font-family: "Segoe UI Light","Segoe UI";
 font-weight: 300;
```

See [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e4365c8e-5ea3-434b-9f42-beffceb958d9/segoe-ui-variants-and-fontweight-property)
This is from a HTML5 solution, but it might help you too, as it's also in Visual Studio...
Hovering over the CSS font-weight options will tell you the weight in words (Light, Semi, etc.)
100: Thin
200: Extra Light (Ultra Light)
300: Light
400: Normal
500: Medium
600: Semi Bold (Demi Bold)
700: Bold
800: Extra Bold
Hope it helps.

Follow the below options and add font-weight instead of using semibold or semilight.Just use 'segoe ui' with combination of font-weight.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: 200;
    src: local("Segoe UI Light");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local("Segoe UI Semilight");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Segoe UI");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local("Segoe UI Semibold");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local("Segoe UI Bold");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Segoe UI Italic");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local("Segoe UI Bold Italic");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be because of various reasons:

1. Perhaps you are using the wrong font format. Chrome supports SVG, WOFF, TTF/OFT.
2. Taken the a wrong approach towards defining font-weight, which leads the browser to interpret the font-weight property wrongly

Sample: http://pastebin.com/FiGvAfTk

Are you defining your fonts properly?

Comment: I'm using TTF type. I tried different approach for assigning the font weight. Nothing works.

Comment: I am using the same code that I have used in the question. Because of this issue I switched to roboto condensed and it is working fine in all the browsers.

Comment: I guess this is one of those chrome specific issues. I ran into a similar issue with Open Sans. Google Chrome bug tracker is filled with similar issues (Google for it, tons of them). They should probably do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting ... I'm having almost the reverse problem ... I can get Segoe UI Light to render properly in Chrome and IE 10, but not in FF 21.

In [another post some time back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172621/why-segoe-ui-light-font-does-not-render-in-firefox-13-0), it was suggested to use something similar to what Microsoft uses on their site ...

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7 {
    font-family: "wf_SegoeUILight","wf_SegoeUI","Segoe UI Light","Segoe WP Light","Segoe UI","Segoe","Segoe WP","Tahoma","Verdana","Arial","sans-serif";
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

For the browsers that don't honor font-weight + the Segoe UI font, specifying Segoe UI Light first seems to guarantee that it renders the lighter weight font.

However, in FF 21, I'm still seeing the normal Segoe UI font regardless of what I try. Firebug indicates that it's choosing the Segoe UI font from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue myself, with the browser only rendering standard Segoe UI as opposed to the lighter version. If you change the font-family to Segoe UI Light it should do what you want.

Please see the revised code below:

```
.divMainHeader {
    font-family:"Segoe UI Light";
    font-size:28pt;
    font-weight:100; 
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myfont';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local('Segoe UI Light'), local('SegoeUI-Light');

}

body{
    font-family: 'Myfont'; 
}
```

this code fixed my problem like yours